# IPV6 wifi vs cellular

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, nsstream

I am a little confused about some aspects of IPv6 if anyone know a bit more than me please fill me in.

First off I use host names with the NSStream class so my app should be IPv6 compliant is this right?  As NSStream should try to connect to the DNS server and get the IPv6 address or a synthesized IPv6 address from a server that is IPv4.

Secondly one of my app testers says the app doesn't work on a cellular connection for him but it does work on wifi.  I said it seems like t-mobile is blocking the connection which we are trying to make.  When the person called them they said that the developer "me" has not upgraded to IPv6.  Can it really work on wifi and not cellular and be me not supporting IPv6?  That just doesn't make any sense to me.

T-Mobile messing with connection article (https://www.grepular.com/Punching_through_The_Great_Firewall_of_TMobile) making me thing they might be messing with my apps connection on cell service.

Comment: I once sat through a T-Mobile presentation on the unique way they handle IPv4/IPv6. T-Mobile _wants_ you to use IPv6, and most of its mobile network is only IPv6, but they have something that can convert IPv6 traffic to IPv4 when needed. You may want to discuss this with T-Mobile.

Comment: Everyone has the converter I believe and it is the DNS 64 servers that synthesize the IPv4 addresses to IPv6 is what the converter is from watching Apples talk on IPv6.  But I will try to get a dialog with T-Mobile going on my end as well.

Comment: T-Mobile is doing something unique. It is not your standard NAT64. It has been a couple of years since the presentation, but they were very proud of it.

Comment: Oh interesting I did not know that I will have to try to find out more it will definitely be interesting to read about it and learn something!